# How to perform the calculation details for field ETC(Cost) in Clarity PPM?

Tags: clarity

One of our report needs the calculation of ETC(Cost) at task level.  While checking I get the general formula:

```
ETC (Cost): Cost of Estimate to Complete
ETC (Cost) = remaining labor cost (ETC * billing rate) + remaining non-labor cost
```

But I am not able find any matched database columns (it is a virtual attribute in Clarity). Expecting the table details where I can query the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual attributes at "Clarity/CA PPM" are "real time" calculated so you will not find the data in a field of task tables.

However, there is a database view where you can find the SQL formula used and even the result(be aware that using data from views is not a best practice)

Check views: ODF_TASK_V and ODF_TASK_V2